# variable scope with inner classes

Tags: java, android, scope

I am creating a `Splash` screen(`Activity`) in my Android app.  I have an inner class which extends `AsyncTask`.  The constructor for this inner class accepts a `Context` object, which is being sent inside the `Splash` activity's `onCreate` method.  There is also reference to a constant `String` field.

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "Splash";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    new SplashAsyncTask(this).execute(new Void[] {});
}
private class SplashAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Context context;
    public SplashAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            if(Constants.LOGGING)
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```

what scope should i be using for the `private static final String TAG = "Splash";` variable? all scopes seem to work fine, but what is proper/more efficient? I notice that eclipse automatically creates the variable with the `public` scope declaration

Also, Do i really need to send the `Context` object to the `SplashAsyncTask` constructor? or can i/should i just use `Splash.this` in all cases where i need a `Context` reference?

Comment: There is no need to send Context Onject to SplashAsynTask. Inner class are just the members of the Outer class and they can access any member variable of outer class.

Comment: I thinks there is no need for splash screen at all, I hate seeing those screens that make me waiting^^ so think about wheather it makes sense or not

Comment: ok then think of it as just another activity(not splash) with an AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

private and public only indicate how your can access your variable, it is more a security thing, ideally all variable of a class should be private and you should access them by a getter and setter method.

I think the word static is more importante here because making a variable is a big thing, it means that the variable can be accessed without making an instance of the and the all share this variable what i mean if you would have made the variable:

```
public static final String TAG = "Splash";
```

then you could access it by writing:

```
Splash.TAG
```

without making an instance of it, but since its private you can´t but it is still a shared variable with all the instances you make of your class Splash

hope this helps